# Keyboard shortcut to delete row in Numbers

Tags: keyboard, numbers

I can add rows conveniently using <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> (insert above) or <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>(insert below).

Is there a keyboard shortcut to **delete the current row**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple has added the ability to delete a row with a keyboard shortcut.
See the attached image.

Delete Rows ALT+CMD+DELETE

[image]

Comment: Duplicate solution to one provided 8 months prior: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/440581/37797

Answer (score 24):

With Numbers 11 and earlier, by default, no, there's no shortcut.

You can create one yourself though:

1. Open **System Preferences** → **Keyboard** → **Shortcuts** → **App Shortcuts**.
2. Click the **+** button to add a new shortcut.
3. Set the **Application** to **Numbers.app**, and the **Menu Title** to **Delete Row**.

   [image]
4. Set your keyboard shortcut and press **Add**.

Comment: Thank you! I set it to Cmd+Shift+D. It doesn't seem to conflict with anything at the moment.

Comment: I found that this works if the Menu Title is Delete Rows instead of Delete Row.

Comment: @htomita The menu title dynamically changes depending on how many rows are selected, so if you want to use the shortcut for more than one row, yes you will need to add that. You can assign a shortcut to both menu titles to work in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

As of at least Numbers 4.3.1, there is a menu item in the Table menu for deleting the current row (as well as one for deleting the current column), with keyboard shortcuts:

Delete Row: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

Delete Column: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

I still had this question (as keycommands are not given in context menu), so the previous answer pointed me to look in the regular menu.
In Numbers 12 it is opt+cmd+del/bs

Comment: Thx for writing this out. Note that this shortcut is shown explicitly next to the Delete Row option under the Table menu in Numbers. The one to remove a column is Control+Command+⌫ as also shown under the Table menu. You can see all Numbers keyboard shortcuts through Help > Keyboard Shortcuts menu option.